# Continuously tunable low-pass filter that "interpolate" wavelet filter for multi-resolution analysis

Tags: lowpass-filter, wavelet

I am using wavelets to analyse some complicated 1D signal, where I am able to come up with multiple filtered signals with different level of details. However, the cutoff of wavelet filters follow a octave distribution, doubling in every additional level. I would like to have a continuously tunable similar filter such that by tuning a parameter, the filtered signal smoothly transit from the coarsest to the finest signal interpolating those from the wavelet filters. Is this possible and efficient to implement?

Comment: Are you using a discrete wavelet transform?

Comment: Yes. I am using R's "dwt" and "idwt" with thresholded wavelet coefficients as a filter.

Comment: Then you have several options, from continuous wavelet transforms (CWT) with discrete approximation, to a lot of better sampled, often redundant discrete wavelets. Do not focus only on the nature of wavelets, the choice of the type of thresholding  plays a great part as well

Comment: One option (though I can't recommend R packages) https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rwave/versions/2.4-8/topics/cwt

Comment: For example, if I choose a smoothly tapered weight function rather than a truncating function to completely turn off a certain level of coefficients, the resulting filter will be continuously tunable by adjusting the "cutoff" frequency of the weight function?

Comment: BTW, I also find R's package "wavelets" to be very unrealiable. What would you recommend instead aside from Matlab?

Comment: I feel sorry, I'm a old Matlab cow. In Python, in Octave, in Scilab, in Julia, there are options. Yet going back to basics: what are your signals, what is you objective?

Comment: I am also Matlab veteran, unfortunately we currently have a license problem. My signal is a very noise 1D stationary signal where I would like to optimize its time stamp to synchronize with another similar signal. I find it easier to first align smoothed signals then adjust at refined level, I would like this refinement to happen continuously along with the optimization instead of stage-wise.

Comment: Whatever, Matlab-like code can work in Octave. From what I understand, you somewhat want to do some matched filtering in the wavelet domain.  We tried that here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.4674.pdf or here https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00914628 Would that match?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the paper with me. It does not look too relevant at first glance, but I will attempt to look further into it.

Comment: If you could state your purpose as some optimization problem, it could help

Comment: My problem is I have f(t) and g(t), I would like to find a monotonic mapping t-> h(t) , such that || f(h(t)) - g(t) || is minimized. In other words, the two signals f and g are not time-synchronized, but the underlying distortion is monotonic ( and hopefully smooth )